# MySql get number of rows

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I try to get number of rows from a table with this :

```
        string commandLine = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client";

        using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandLine, connect))
        {
            connect.Open();

            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            return count;
        }
```

And i get the exception:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: use the debugger to see what type `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` actually returns

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandLine, connect))
{
    connect.Open();
    return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: +1 - I believe that the `COUNT` function in the MySQL server returns a long (BIGINT) by default, so that is what is returned from ExecuteScalar.  Assuming the table has fewer than 2 billion or so rows, this should be safe.

Comment: @EricPetroelje hope fully... finger crossed :D

Answer (score 2):

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandLine, connect))
{
        connect.Open();
        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

**EDIT:** Make also sure to handle exceptions in your code (E.g. if there is SQL Connection Error).
Also, if it's not a `COUNT(*)` the value returned by `ExecuteScalar()` **can be null (!)**

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the cast, you can use:

```
long count = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

As mentioned above, COUNT in MySql returns BIGINT, hence casting with an int fails.