# How to show the number of rows returned from a SQL query using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to show a MessageBox in C# that has how many rows are listed.

[image: Screenshot of the SQL query with a table of the results below. The table contains two rows.]

In this case I want to show "2" in a MessageBox in C#.

My SQL:

```
SELECT ogrno, COUNT(ogrno) FROM Sonuc WHERE sinavno='" + sinavno + "' GROUP BY ogrno
```

My C# code:

```
mdl.mysqlbaglan.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ogrno, COUNT(distinct ogrno) FROM Sonuc WHERE sinavno = '" + sinavno + "' GROUP BY ogrno", mdl.mysqlbaglan)

MySqlDataReader oku3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

oku3.Read();    

{
    MessageBox.Show(oku3.GetInt64(1).ToString());
}

mdl.mysqlbaglan.Close();
```

Comment: How are you calling the query from C#?

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ogrno, COUNT(ogrno) FROM Sonuc WHERE sinavno='" + sinavno + "' GROUP BY ogrno", mdl.mysqlbaglan);

Comment: Use AS in query to create a Column name for resutls :  COUNT(ogrno) AS XXXXX.  Then get results like any other column using XXXXX.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/LHhTL
I just want too see "2" on messagebox, I only get "1"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285071/mysql-get-number-of-rows

Comment: Please show your C# code for calling this query

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/LHhTL @MadMyche

Comment: 2 rows are listing on this sql I just want to show that, why its so hard :D

Comment: Future reference- posting your code as an image really dissuades people from working with your code

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ogrno, COUNT(DISTINCT ogrno) FROM Sonuc 
WHERE sinavno='" + sinavno + "' GROUP BY ogrno
```

Since there is where clause which filter the result set; above query will count the filtered result set's distinct orgno.  If you want result to be filtered and also want to know how many records in table then one of the possible way is to use sub query.

```
SELECT ogrno, (Select COUNT(ogrno)) as Count FROM Sonuc 
WHERE sinavno='" + sinavno + "' GROUP BY ogrno
```

Comment: I got "1" but it should be "2" you know

Comment: How many records you have in your table and what is your requirement. Please elaborate in your question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/19N1ORl thats how many record I have. there is a 2 diffrent number, "ogrno"

Comment: SELECT ogrno, (Select COUNT(ogrno)) as Count FROM Sonuc WHERE sinavno='" + sinavno + "' GROUP BY ogrno
in this what should I write on messagebox oku3.GetInt64(1).ToString ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know the count of a specific value and you do not need anything else from the result set, you can elimininate the GROUP BY, the *ogrno* column, and the `DataReader`. We can replace all of this with this the simple `ExecuteScalar()` method which only returns the first row of the first column of the result set. If there is no return it will throw an error, and the `catch` will then asign the value of *-1*.

And as is good practice; I removed the inline variable from your SQL statement and replaced with paramater. I also wrapped withing a `using` block as this is a disposable object.

```
string query3 = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Sonuc WHERE sinavno = @sinavno";
Int64 result3;

using(MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(query3, mdl.mysqlbaglan)) {
    cmd3.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@sinavno", sinavno);

    try {
        mdl.mysqlbaglan.Open();
        result3 = (Int64)cmd3.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        result3 = -1;
        // your exception handling
    }
    finally {
        mdl.mysqlbaglan.Close();
        // any other cleanup
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(result3.ToString());
```